# Custom ColumnTree node attributes

Tags: extjs

By default, ColumnTree uses these attributes for the nodes: `text, id, leaf`. So, the server sould sends something like

```
{
    id: 1,
    text: 'A leaf Node',
    leaf: true
}
```

What should i change in the ColumnTree options if my server sends custom params? Like:

```
{
    n: 1,
    folder: 'A leaf Node',
    leaf: true
}
```

Comment: What is a ColumnTree? I don't see it in the ExtJS documentation.

Comment: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/column-tree.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method [createNode](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.tree.TreeLoader) and assemble your own attributes hash from the data you received from the server. Check the example in the docs of [Ext.tree.TreeLoader.createNode](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.tree.TreeLoader)